# Close popoup when user start input

Tags: android

I have app with edittext where user simply  writes something with the softkeyboard. After user will click at the button and he will see popupwindow, in this case user still have seen keyboard. When user will click outside the popup, it should disappear, and it work ok, but if user will click at keyboard, popup won't disappear. Maybe someone has deal with same problem and can help me.

Steps:

1. Open app
2. Invoke keyboard
3. Invoke popupwindow
4. Start input

result: Popup is not hidden, text is not inputted

Comment: @Anna its quite unclear, can you please be specific?

Comment: @pratik I added steps

Comment: @Anna an you please send me a code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want that the keyboard to disapper when the user clicks on it?
If so, do this for your EditText:

```
                final EditText sample = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.popupET);
            sample.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(sample.getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {                        
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                      
                }
            });
```

What it does is simply wait for the user to input any key (press on the keyboard) and then it hides it.

The sample EditText is the field you currently have in your code.

Let me know if everything works

Comment: No, I want to popup window hiding when user start inputting.I tried to use TextWatcher, but when user was starting input, nothing was inputted and TextWatcher didn't call.